# How to view pdf without downloading in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pdf

want to view pdf in the browser, but it started downloading automatically by IDM.

Here is my controller code ,

```
   $filename = Pdf::find($id);
   $path     = asset($filename->pdf);

    return Response::make(file_get_contents($path), 200, [
        'Content-Type'        => 'application/pdf',
        'Content-Disposition' => 'inline; filename="' . $filename . '"',
    ]);
```

Here is my blade code,

```
      <a href="{{route('preview.pdf',[$pdf->id])}}">view</a>
```

When I click on the view button, it started downloading automatically by IDM. I want to prevent it. No one can download the pdf, user can only view the pdf.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: The [Content-Disposition = inline;](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) should make it to display in your browser, however `inline` is normally used without the `filename` directive.

Comment: its worth pointing out even if you just set it up to display the pdf the user can still choose to save it if they want to. Its still physically downloading onto their machine.

Comment: I wonder what IDM is?!

Comment: IDM => Internet Donwload Manager

Comment: Have you tried disabling/stopping IDM?

Answer (score 1):

> The file method may be used to display a file, such as an image or PDF, directly in the user's browser instead of initiating a download

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/responses#file-responses

According to the documentation, we should use this way.

To prevent forced downloads by IDM, in IDM configuration, you could do the following 2 ways:

1. Remove `PDF` type
2. Specify your address where IDM will not download automatically

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Laravel responce has a special `file()`:

```
return response()->file($pathToFile);
```

Comment: I applied this code & result is same. Pdf is started downloading automatically by IDM.